# Function for dumping entire mysql table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a simple function that creates an HTML table that first gets the headers in th-tags and then dumps all the rows into html table rows.

Here's what I got so far.

```
function dumpMysqlTable($tblName) {
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `$tblName`");
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
$i=0;
while($i<mysql_num_fields($result)) {
    $fields=mysql_fetch_field($result, $i);
    echo "<th>".$fields->name."</th>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
$j=0;
while($j<mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    $k=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<td>".$row[$k]."</td>";
        $k++;
    }
    $j++;
}
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
```

However, it messes up badly, and picks rows from the table its not supposed to and I just can't get it to work. Please help :)

Comment: What you get and what you want to get?

Comment: Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: As I said in the question, I want a function that displays any given mysql table as an HTML table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making several mistakes.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
```

will return a whole row (or line) of the table. So `$row[$k]` references a row (one line in the table), **not** a cell value.

Then you should know that `mysql_fetch_array` by default will return an array with both numerical keys and associative indices. So you should either use `mysql_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_NUM )` or simply [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php). Then you can loop through the row:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $result ) ) {
  echo "<tr>";

  foreach( $row as $cell )
  {
    echo "<td>".$cell."</td>";
  }

  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Notice you also forgot to open a new `tr` for each line.

Comment: Thanks, man! I was messing around with the code, originally I did have the `tr` on each line. It works now, thanks a lot!